How to make the colon same align
From this code.
\begin{enumerate}[align=left,label=(\arabic*) :]
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
\end{enumerate}

Will get this. How make the colon stay in the same align.


You can set the enumeration numbering inside a box of similar width, followed by the colon:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[align=left,label={\makebox[1.75em][l]{(\arabic*)} :}]
  \item x
  \item x
  \item x
  \item x
  \item x
  \item x
  \item x
  \item x
  \item x
  \item x
  \item x
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

You could be more specific and measure the widest element, but a rough estimate (1.75em) is sufficient. Make sure you also update the ref key if you want to include references to some of the \items (and choose a more simple definition, like ref=(\arabic*)).

I would suggest you switch from align=left to align=right.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class. 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[align=right,label=(\arabic*) :]
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

